# Add ContactList on Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I want retrieve contacts from the address book on a BlackBerry.  I can get the contacts using the following code:

```
AddressBookArguments abArg = new AddressBookArguments();
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_ADDRESSBOOK, abArg);
```

However I cannot access the selected contact in my application.  How can I display the selected contact in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
BlackBerryContactList list = (BlackBerryContactList) PIM.getInstance().
                             openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
BlackBerryContact contact = (BlackBerryContact) list.choose();
```